# hangouts-chat bot starting hangouts chat or rooms

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts, google-chat

I'm planning some kind of Google Hangouts bot/integration which is not following premises from code samples at:
https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/

This won't be a "reply-bot" for incoming messages, it will start conversation-chats or rooms proactively to get people in contact.

From my application, I expect to make questions to users like:
"Hello!
John Doe has requested access to your server.
Do you allow him to get access?
(Allowed responses: yes/no)"

So, they guy might reply: "yes"
And all the devops mechanism will be triggered.

Similar use-case for many people (chat room for i.e. the unix team):
(Here no response is expected, just to start room chat)
"Critical incident at our main router detected
All of you where identified as responsible to solve this issue."

I would really appreciate any suggestion or whatever on how to approach this.

Best regards to everyone!   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hangout Chat bots are currently not allowed to proactively contact people. They will need a person to add them first before being able to make interactions.